# How do I mount a junction box behind a vinyl mounting block?

Tags: electrical, light, junction-box, vinyl-siding

What type of box do I use to get the junction box flush with the mounting block?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It depends how much space you have behind the block.

Comment: Assuming you have space, an old work plastic box would be ideal, as you could position it exactly where you want. There are adjustable depth ones, but they screw to studs, so Murphy’s law would make that off-center.